# Download video from vimeo with out URL is geting?

Tags: android, download, vimeo

I need to Download Vimeo viodes in my app having no video id. How can I get vimeo video url? Or is there any other way to download  video in android?

Answer (score 0):

Download capability is only provided to PRO members requesting their own videos, from their own API app.

If this is what you are looking for, you should be able to see download links on every video in https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos